# Adding an event listener to jQuery code

Tags: jquery, html, css, event-handling

I'm using some jQuery for a carousel image slider that has two buttons: next image and previous image.  How would I add a mouse click event listener to both buttons such that when either button is clicked corresponding text is printed below the slider, producing a picture slideshow where each picture is associated with some text?  Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
  jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

  $('#checkbox').change(function(){
    setInterval(function () {
    moveRight();
   }, 3000);
 });

var slideCount = $('#slider ul li').length;
var slideWidth = $('#slider ul li').width();
var slideHeight = $('#slider ul li').height();
var sliderUlWidth = slideCount * slideWidth;

$('#slider').css({ width: slideWidth, height: slideHeight });

$('#slider ul').css({ width: sliderUlWidth, marginLeft: - slideWidth });

$('#slider ul li:last-child').prependTo('#slider ul');

function moveLeft() {
    $('#slider ul').animate({
        left: + slideWidth
    }, 200, function () {
        $('#slider ul li:last-child').prependTo('#slider ul');
        $('#slider ul').css('left', '');
    });
};

function moveRight() {
    $('#slider ul').animate({
        left: - slideWidth
    }, 200, function () {
        $('#slider ul li:first-child').appendTo('#slider ul');
        $('#slider ul').css('left', '');
    });
};

$('button.control_prev').click(function () {
    moveLeft();
});

$('button.control_next').click(function () {
    moveRight();
});

});  

</script>
<style>

@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,600);  

nav { 
float: left;
background-color: #EEEFFF;
height: 1500px;
width: 100px;
}

html {
border-top: 5px solid #fff;
background: #58DDAF;
color: #2a2a2a;
}

html, body {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
font-family: 'Open Sans';
}

h1 {
color: #fff;
text-align: center;
font-weight: 300;
}

#slider {
position: relative;
overflow: hidden;
margin: 20px auto 0 auto;
border-radius: 4px;
}

#slider ul {
position: relative;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
height: 200px;
list-style: none;
}

#slider ul li {
position: relative;
display: block;
float: left;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
width: 500px;
height: 300px;
background: #ccc;
text-align: center;
line-height: 300px;
}

button.control_prev, button.control_next {
position: absolute;
top: 40%;
z-index: 999;
display: block;
padding: 4% 3%;
width: auto;
height: auto;
background: #2a2a2a;
color: #fff;
text-decoration: none;
font-weight: 600;
font-size: 18px;
opacity: 0.8;
cursor: pointer;
border:solid transparent;
}

button.control_prev:hover, button.control_next:hover {
opacity: 1;
-webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease;
}

button.control_prev {
border-radius: 0 2px 2px 0;
}

button.control_next {
right: 0;
border-radius: 2px 0 0 2px;
}

.slider_option {
position: relative;
margin: 10px auto;
width: 160px;
font-size: 18px;
}

</style>
</head>

<body>
<nav>
test
</nav>
<div id="slider">
  <button class="control_next"></button>
  <button class="control_prev"></button>
    <ul>
     <li>SLIDE 1</li>
     <li style="background: #aaa;">SLIDE 2</li>
     <li>SLIDE 3</li>
     <li style="background: #aaa;">SLIDE 4</li>
    </ul>  
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've made slight changes to your below 2 functions:

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/thb5prt7/1/)**

```
function moveLeft() {
    $('#slider ul').animate({
        left: + slideWidth
    }, 200, function () {
        $('#slider ul li:last-child').prependTo('#slider ul');
        $('#slider ul').css('left', '');

    });
    var current=$("li.active"); //get the current active li
    var prev=current.prev('li'); //get its prev li
    current.removeClass('active'); //remove active from current li
    if(prev.length==0) //if no previous element is present
        $('li:last').addClass('active'); //make last li as active
    else
        prev.addClass('active'); //make prev li active
    var cur=$('li.active').attr('data-des'); once active is set to prev or next li get its data-des attribute
    $('.imageDes').fadeOut('500').text(cur).fadeIn('500'); //set it to a div

};

function moveRight() {
    $('#slider ul').animate({
        left: - slideWidth
    }, 200, function () {
        $('#slider ul li:first-child').appendTo('#slider ul');
        $('#slider ul').css('left', '');
    });
    var current=$("li.active");
    var next=current.next('li');
    current.removeClass('active');
    if(next.length==0)
        $('li:first').addClass('active');
    else
        next.addClass('active');
    var cur=$('li.active').attr('data-des');
    $('.imageDes').fadeOut('500').text(cur).fadeIn('500');
};
```

See in line comments on `moveLeft()` which goes same with `moveRight()` too.

Your html:

```
<div class="imageDes">Image 1</div><!--this is where you display your corresponding text-->
<button class="control_next"></button>
<button class="control_prev"></button>
<ul>
   <!--Added extra attribute to each li with name data-des-->
   <li class="active" data-des="Image 1">SLIDE 1</li> 
   <li data-des="Image 2" style="background: #aaa;">SLIDE 2</li>
   <li data-des="Image 3">SLIDE 3</li>
   <li data-des="Image 4" style="background: #aaa;">SLIDE 4</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: My corresponding text needs to be more like a single sentence or a short paragraph, as opposed to a data-des.  Is there any way I can call a string variable from data-des that will print more text, because it seems like data-des is simply an inline attribute that is meant for very brief desriptions?

Comment: Can you give an example pls!! From where you wanna get this corresponding text?

Comment: Imagine a button such that when you click it, a paragraph of text then appears.  Now imagine my picture slider.  It has a next and previous button.  Now imagine that each picture has a corresponding paragraph of text, such that when you click the next or previous button, the next or previous image and its corresponding paragraph of text appears.  Your code simply supplies a description using inline html markup and is only intended for several words, whereas I'm looking for the event listener to trigger more like a paragraph of text.

Comment: Inside each `li` you will be having an element say `div` or `p` which contains description for that image? where will be corresponding paragraph placed?? html structure if you have any would help much!

Comment: All of my code is posted in my question above.  It isn't so much an "image desription" as it is several sentences of text.  It's an instruction set.  Imagine yourself reading a set of instructions with pictures.  That's what this is.  When the next button is clicked, the next image and sentences of text appear.   The text should be below the image, but this isn't a make-or-break requirement.  The real issue is that I am going to need to display more text than a couple of words.  That is the issue: I need to display more text than a couple of words...

Comment: I can make it but where it will be placed in DOM!! I need to know that! In your above question you haven't mentioned anytime about description with each image! I don't find it in html given in your question! From where you wanna display it? To be short where you will place the descriptions in your html!!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84088/discussion-between-digital-impermanence-and-guruprasad-rao).

Comment: Check this **[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/thb5prt7/7/)** @DigitalImpermanence.. I hope this is what you want!

Answer (score 0):

Based on Guruprasad Rao's answer, I just update a bit change:

Before the "once active is set to prev or next li get its data-des attribute", you forget the "//".

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
  jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

  $('#checkbox').change(function(){
    setInterval(function () {
    moveRight();
   }, 3000);
 });

var slideCount = $('#slider ul li').length;
var slideWidth = $('#slider ul li').width();
var slideHeight = $('#slider ul li').height();
var sliderUlWidth = slideCount * slideWidth;

$('#slider').css({ width: slideWidth, height: slideHeight });

$('#slider ul').css({ width: sliderUlWidth, marginLeft: - slideWidth });

$('#slider ul li:last-child').prependTo('#slider ul');

/*function moveLeft() {
    $('#slider ul').animate({
        left: + slideWidth
    }, 200, function () {
        $('#slider ul li:last-child').prependTo('#slider ul');
        $('#slider ul').css('left', '');
    });
};

function moveRight() {
    $('#slider ul').animate({
        left: - slideWidth
    }, 200, function () {
        $('#slider ul li:first-child').appendTo('#slider ul');
        $('#slider ul').css('left', '');
    });
};*/
function moveLeft() {
    $('#slider ul').animate({
        left: + slideWidth
    }, 200, function () {
        $('#slider ul li:last-child').prependTo('#slider ul');
        $('#slider ul').css('left', '');

    });
    var current=$("li.active"); //get the current active li
    var prev=current.prev('li'); //get its prev li
    current.removeClass('active'); //remove active from current li
    if(prev.length==0) //if no previous element is present
        $('li:last').addClass('active'); //make last li as active
    else
        prev.addClass('active'); //make prev li active
    var cur=$('li.active').attr('data-des'); //once active is set to prev or next li get its data-des attribute
    $('.imageDes').fadeOut('500').text(cur).fadeIn('500'); //set it to a div

};

function moveRight() {
    $('#slider ul').animate({
        left: - slideWidth
    }, 200, function () {
        $('#slider ul li:first-child').appendTo('#slider ul');
        $('#slider ul').css('left', '');
    });
    var current=$("li.active");
    var next=current.next('li');
    current.removeClass('active');
    if(next.length==0)
        $('li:first').addClass('active');
    else
        next.addClass('active');
    var cur=$('li.active').attr('data-des');
    $('.imageDes').fadeOut('500').text(cur).fadeIn('500');
};

$('button.control_prev').click(function () {
    moveLeft();
});

$('button.control_next').click(function () {
    moveRight();
});

});  

</script>
<style>

@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,600);  

nav { 
float: left;
background-color: #EEEFFF;
height: 1500px;
width: 100px;
}

html {
border-top: 5px solid #fff;
background: #58DDAF;
color: #2a2a2a;
}

html, body {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
font-family: 'Open Sans';
}

h1 {
color: #fff;
text-align: center;
font-weight: 300;
}

#slider {
position: relative;
overflow: hidden;
margin: 20px auto 0 auto;
border-radius: 4px;
}

#slider ul {
position: relative;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
height: 200px;
list-style: none;
}

#slider ul li {
position: relative;
display: block;
float: left;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
width: 500px;
height: 300px;
background: #ccc;
text-align: center;
line-height: 300px;
}

button.control_prev, button.control_next {
position: absolute;
top: 40%;
z-index: 999;
display: block;
padding: 4% 3%;
width: auto;
height: auto;
background: #2a2a2a;
color: #fff;
text-decoration: none;
font-weight: 600;
font-size: 18px;
opacity: 0.8;
cursor: pointer;
border:solid transparent;
}

button.control_prev:hover, button.control_next:hover {
opacity: 1;
-webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease;
}

button.control_prev {
border-radius: 0 2px 2px 0;
}

button.control_next {
right: 0;
border-radius: 2px 0 0 2px;
}

.slider_option {
position: relative;
margin: 10px auto;
width: 160px;
font-size: 18px;
}

</style>
</head>

<body>
<nav>
test
</nav>
<div id="slider">
  <!-- <button class="control_next"></button>
   <button class="control_prev"></button>
     <ul>
      <li>SLIDE 1</li>
      <li style="background: #aaa;">SLIDE 2</li>
      <li>SLIDE 3</li>
      <li style="background: #aaa;">SLIDE 4</li>
     </ul>  --> 
    <div class="imageDes">Image 1</div><!--this is where you display your corresponding text-->
    <button class="control_next"></button>
    <button class="control_prev"></button>
    <ul>
       <!--Added extra attribute to each li with name data-des-->
       <li class="active" data-des="Image 1">SLIDE 1</li> 
       <li data-des="Image 2" style="background: #aaa;">SLIDE 2</li>
       <li data-des="Image 3">SLIDE 3</li>
       <li data-des="Image 4" style="background: #aaa;">SLIDE 4</li>
    </ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```